# The type initializer for 'XConnectModel.UserModel' threw an exception while generate the custom model json

Tags: xconnect

We are trying to generate the `custom model json` using a simple console application but getting error below error:
The type initializer for `XConnectModel.UserModel` threw an exception.

We are using `Sitecore 10.1`.

For reference we have added a snapshot as well as a sample application which you can run and check.

[image]

UserModel.cs looks like below-

[image]

And PulsePoll.cs file has below code-

[image]

Please help us in detecting the issue.

Note: we have crossed check the code implementation using this link: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-custom-model.html

Comment: Can you share the content of your other classes please? PulsePoll.cs and UserModel.cs

Comment: @DeanOBrien I updated the question with the detail you asked. Thanks.

Comment: Please try making your PulsePoll() empty constructor public not private

Comment: Also - please switch to use text rather than images in your question for SEO purposes

Comment: Did you ever try switching to public constructor?